# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. _Pnext было 0x49B2DC

Tags: c++

Программа должна делать две вещи: записывать структуру Book в бинарный файл и искать по некоторым ключам нужные записи в файле и выводить в таблице.
Выполняется почти все, но когда завершается вывод таблицы, то компилятор выкидывает сообщение о нарушении доступа для чтения. В чем может быть проблема?

Код:

```
int main()
   {
////////////////////////////////////Variables

string          path="d:\\catalog.dat";
unsigned int    input;
char            choice;
string          key;

////////////////////////////////////Enter path of file

cout << "Enter path of file: ";
//cin >> path;


fstream file(path.c_str(),
        ios::in |
        ios::out    &
        ios::binary);


if (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error. File don't exist. Do you wanna create new catalog here? (y/n)\n"
        << ">:";
    file.close();
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice != 'y' && choice != 'n')
    {
        if (choice == 'y')
        {
            fstream fileOut(path.c_str(),
                    ios::binary |
                    ios::app);
            fileOut.close();
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'n') break;
        cout << "Please enter yes(y) or not(n)!\n"; 
        continue;
    }


    if (choice == 'n')
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Error. File don't exist. Please repeat.\n>:";
        cin >> path;
        fstream file(path.c_str(),
                    std::ios::in |
                    std::ios::out   &
                    ios::binary);

        if (file.is_open() == true)
        {
            file.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

}


cout << "File has been opened.\n\n";

////////////////////////////////////Interface/////


cout    << "1.Enter data about books.\n"
        << "2.Search notes in catalog.\n"
        << "3.Exit.\n";


while (true)
{
    cout << ">:";   cin >> input;

    if (input == 1)
    {
        ofstream fileOut(path.c_str(), ofstream::app | ofstream::out & ofstream::binary);
        Book newBook;


        //Enterign data into file
        cout << "Enter data about book:\n";
        cout << "Title:\n\t";           cin >> newBook.title;
        cout << "Author:\n\t";          cin >> newBook.author;
        cout << "Genre:\n\t";           cin >> newBook.genre;
        cout << "Reliaser:\n\t";        cin >> newBook.reliaser;
        cout << "Number Of Page:\n\t";  cin >> newBook.numberOfPage;
        cout << "Price:\n\t";           cin >> newBook.price;
        cout << "Year Of Reliase:\n\t"; cin >> newBook.yearOfReliase;


        fileOut.write((char*)&newBook, sizeof(newBook));
        fileOut.close();

    }

    if (input == 2)
    {
        vector<Book>        catalog;
        Book                readedBook;
        fstream             file(path.c_str(),
                                ios::binary |
                                ios::in |
                                ios::out);
        string              Author,     keyAuthor,
                            Genre,      keyGenre,
                            Reliaser,   keyReliaser,
                            Title,      keyTitle;
        unsigned int        Year,       keyYear,
                            Pages,      keyPages;
        double              Price,      keyPrice;



        //Pushing lines from file in list
        while (file.read((char*)&readedBook, sizeof(Book)))
        {
            catalog.push_back(readedBook);
        }
        file.close();


        keyAuthor="JonnyB";
        keyGenre="-1";
        keyReliaser = "-1";
        keyTitle = "-1";
        keyYear = -1;
        keyPages = -1;
        keyPrice = -1;


        //Entering key
        /*
        cout << "Enter the keys of interest to you.\n(Enter \"-1\" if you don\'t want search with this key.)\n";    
        cout << "Author: ";         cin >> keyAuthor;
        cout << "Genre: ";          cin >> keyGenre;
        cout << "Reliaser: ";       cin >> keyReliaser;
        cout << "Title: ";          cin >> keyTitle;
        cout << "Year: ";           cin >> keyYear;
        cout << "Pages: ";          cin >> keyPages;
        cout << "Price: ";          cin >> keyPrice;
        */

        cout << "_______________________________________________________________________________\n";
        cout.width(15);cout << "Author |";  cout.width(10);cout << "Genre |";   cout.width(15);cout << "Reliaser |";
        cout.width(20);cout << "Title |";   cout.width(5);cout << "Year |";     cout.width(7);cout << "Pages |";
        cout.width(7);cout << "Price |";
        cout << "_______________________________________________________________________________\n";

        int size = catalog.size();
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {   
            if (keyAuthor == "-1")      Author = catalog[i].author;     //Если ключ не интересует, то мы просто 
            else                        Author = keyAuthor;             //копируем значение из текущей записи и так для каждого поля записи
            if (keyGenre == "-1")       Genre = catalog[i].genre;
            else                        Genre = keyGenre;
            if (keyReliaser == "-1")    Reliaser = catalog[i].reliaser;
            else                        Reliaser = keyReliaser;
            if (keyTitle == "-1")       Title = catalog[i].title;
            else                        Title = keyTitle;
            if (keyYear == -1)          Year = catalog[i].yearOfReliase;
            else                        Year = keyYear;
            if (keyPages == -1)         Pages = catalog[i].numberOfPage;
            else                        Pages = keyPages;
            if (keyPrice == -1)         Price = catalog[i].price;
            else                        Price = keyPrice;

            if (Author      == catalog[i].author &&                     //Проверка на идентичность записи, если выполнится, то выведится 
                Genre       == catalog[i].genre &&
                Reliaser    == catalog[i].reliaser &&
                Title       == catalog[i].title &&
                Year        == catalog[i].yearOfReliase &&
                Pages       == catalog[i].numberOfPage &&
                Price       == catalog[i].price)
            {
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(13);       cout << catalog[i].author << " |";
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(8);        cout << catalog[i].genre << " |";
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(13);       cout << catalog[i].reliaser << " |";
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(18);       cout << catalog[i].title << " |";
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(3);        cout << catalog[i].yearOfReliase << " |";
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(5);        cout << catalog[i].numberOfPage << " |";
                cout.flags(ios::left);cout.width(5);        cout << catalog[i].price << " |";
            }
        }


        cout << "_______________________________________________________________________________\n";


    }

    if (input == 3)
    {
        file.close();
        exit(0);
    }
}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Некоторые блоки закоментированы для того, чтобы часто не вводить некоторые значения.

Comment: Покажите вашу структуру `Book`, что-то ее объявления не видно...

Comment: @Harry Вот:
`struct Book
{
 string   title;
 string   author;
 string   genre;
 string   reliaser;
 double   price;
 unsigned int yearOfReliase;
 unsigned int numberOfPage;
};`

Comment: Вот еслибы вы все написали на C++, с обьктно ориентированным подходом, а не  местами, то у вас код был бы проще и  вероятность ошибок было бы гораздо меньше.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, такова лабораторная работа, суть которой написать программу в разных стилях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это:

```
string title;
```

и прочие в составе класса `Book` делает недопустимым запись и чтение с помощью функций `write` и `read` из памяти. Потому что в `title` содержится, например, не сама строка, а указатель на нее. При записи вы сохраняете в файле какой-то адрес, потом считываете его - когда он уже давно не актуален, а при удалении вызов деструктора пытается удалить память по несуществующему адресу...

Такие классы нужно записывать и читать иначе - например, в вашем случае для `double` или `unsigned`-поля можно писать и так, но вот `title` я бы писал так - сначала размер строки, потом содержимое. При чтении - читал размер, выделял буфер, в него читал строку, а потом уже инициализировал ею поле `title`.

Но вот такое -

```
fileOut.write((char*)&newBook, sizeof(newBook));
file.read((char*)&readedBook, sizeof(Book))
```

это дорога в испорченную память... У вас слетает не мгновенно только потому, что запись и чтение идут в одной программе, с одинаковыми адресами. Если записать так файл при первом вызове программы, затем выйти и считать - то слет будет тут же, ничего разумного программа не выведет...

Comment: Я не совсем до конца понимаю, как подобное исправить?

Comment: Полностью переписать. Каждое поле записывать отдельно. Я здесь уже раз 10, не меньше отве6чал на эти вопросы - просто поищите на сайте...